# SQL Syntax replace for SSRS Expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssrs-2008

I have a expression in SSRS as below.

```
=IIF(Fields!Availability.Value = "GREEN", 
     "N/A",
      IIF(Fields!sg3a.Value = nothing, 
          Fields!Typeof3a.Value, 
          Fields!sg3a.Value & vbcrlf & Fields!Typeof3a.Value
      )
)
```

I have a situation to replace this expression to get the result directly from the data set, as I have to write other expression in place of current and the sql equivalent of the expression is as below.

```
case when Availability='GREEN' then 
    'N/A' else 
     case when sg3a is null then TypeOf3a else 
         sg3a +' ' +TypeOf3a 
     end 
end as  sg3a,
```

While the SSRS expression is working as expected from the query i am not getting the expected result. I am getting `NULL` for some rows.

Comment: If there is a possibility that TypeOf3a could be null you should code for it because the result of a string concatenation will be null if any of the elements are null.

Comment: This query has the possibility of failure if sg3a is some sort of numeric data type.

Comment: Look what @P.Salmon said , you should use isnull() at your columns... Like isnull(sg3a,'') for example.

Comment: Can you give an example of a row that works in SSRS, but returns NULL in SQL?